# Gradle doesnt seem to be able to find my file

Tags: java, gradle

I'm at 21 minutes in this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dtcEMLNmn0

Basically im trying to get my first java build to run using gradle and im getting this error

Error: Could not find or load main class com.cestmoi.gradle_tut
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cestmoi.gradle_tut

the image below shows my entire project, including A tree of all my files,  my .java file
, my build.gradle file and my the command line instructions I have use

[this image shows everything you might need to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukXZV.png)

im using gradle version 8.5

and java version 17.0.7 2023-04-18 LTS

1. Why might i be getting this error?
2. How can i fix it?
3. what more info do you need?

###### ps

if you cant see my directories easily to the left of the image here is what i get from "tree in the cmd line"

```
C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\java\gradle_tut>tree /F
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is C037-C26A
C:.
│   .gitattributes
│   .gitignore
│   build.gradle
│   gradlew
│   gradlew.bat
│   settings.gradle
│
├───.gradle
│   │   file-system.probe
│   │
│   ├───8.5
│   │   │   gc.properties
│   │   │
│   │   ├───checksums
│   │   │       checksums.lock
│   │   │
│   │   ├───dependencies-accessors
│   │   │       dependencies-accessors.lock
│   │   │       gc.properties
│   │   │
│   │   ├───executionHistory
│   │   │       executionHistory.bin
│   │   │       executionHistory.lock
│   │   │
│   │   ├───fileChanges
│   │   │       last-build.bin
│   │   │
│   │   ├───fileHashes
│   │   │       fileHashes.bin
│   │   │       fileHashes.lock
│   │   │
│   │   └───vcsMetadata
│   ├───buildOutputCleanup
│   │       buildOutputCleanup.lock
│   │       cache.properties
│   │       outputFiles.bin
│   │
│   └───vcs-1
│           gc.properties
│
├───build
│   ├───libs
│   │       gradle_tut.jar
│   │
│   └───tmp
│       └───jar
│               MANIFEST.MF
│
└───gradle
    │   libs.versions.toml
    │
    ├───src
    │   └───main
    │       └───java
    │           └───com
    │               └───cestmoi
    │                       gradle_tut.java
    │
    └───wrapper
            gradle-wrapper.jar
            gradle-wrapper.properties
```

gradle_tut.java below

```
package com.cestmoi;


public class gradle_tut {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("oh my days");
    }
}
```

build.gradle below

```
plugins{
    id 'java'
}

jar{
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.cestmoi.gradle_tut'
    }
}
```

Comment: *if you cant see my directories easily to the left of the image here is what i get from "tree in the cmd line"* That's much better than a picture - but ... there's no source that I can see

Comment: Hi i updated my question to include that too

Comment: `src/main/java` should be at the root of your project not nested inside of some other folder

Comment: Spot on @Roddy of the Frozen Peas

thank you

Answer (score 3):

Roddy of the Frozen Peas was correct when [he said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77863407/gradle-doesnt-seem-to-be-able-to-find-my-file#comment137268404_77863407):

> `src/main/java` should be at the root of your project not nested inside of some other folder